# Multi nested form in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a scenario where my application interacts with three models called User, Question and Answer. I added three questions for a user from admin panel or through rails console. Now in separate action i need to display all the questions of a particular user and providing a option of adding multiple answers as text for each. I don't know how to proceed further. Here is my sample code which i tried.

```
   class User
     has_many :questions
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
   end

   class Question
     belongs_to :user
     has_many :answers
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
   end

   class Answer
      belongs_to :question
   end

   users_controller.rb
   class UserController
    def display_questions
      @user = current_user
    end
   end

   views/display_questions.html.erb
   <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
       <%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| %>
         <%= q.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
             <%= a.text_field :name %>
         <% end %>
         <%= q.link_to_add 'Add', :answers %>
       <% end %>
   <% end %>
```

I am getting all the questions for that user but not able to add answers for individual question. I am confused how to build nested fields for these scenario, any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem it's pretty easy, just do:

```
<%= nested_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions do |q| %>
        <%= q.fields_for :answers do |a| %>
            <%= a.text_field :name %>
        <% end %>
        <%= q.link_to_add 'Add', :answers %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Note the **nested_form_for** instead of **form_for**

Also, you will need to add the property [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) for the models which correspond:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: I tried that but its showing me invalid association.Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :answers association.

Comment: Edited answer to add that.